# Добавление в избранное в БД при нажатии на кнопку в item RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite

Получился такой MainActivity, который реализует интерфейс клика из адаптера. Пытаюсь реализовать добавление в избранное, но при клике на кнопку "В избранное" на пункте списка ничего не происходит

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, BludaAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private BludaAdapter bludaAdapter;
    private int currentLoader;
    final private static int LOADER_BLUDA = 0;

    RecyclerView rvList;

    DBHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,
                layoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        db = new DBHelper(this);

        rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);

        bludaAdapter = new BludaAdapter(this);
        rvList.setAdapter(bludaAdapter);
        bludaAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString("filter", "");

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_BLUDA, bundle, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        // переменная id - ID записи, по которой кликнули в списке
        Toast.makeText(this, id+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite) {
        // переменная id - ID записи, по которой кликнули (для обращения к БД)
        // переменная isFavorite - состояние избранного в записи перед нажатием на кнопку
        Toast.makeText(this, isFavorite+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int fav = 0;
        String table = Contract.Bluda.TAB_BLUDA;

        if (isFavorite) {
            fav = 0;
            isFavorite = false;
            Toast.makeText(this, "fav = 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            fav = 1;
            isFavorite = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "fav = 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Contract.Bluda.COL_LIKE, fav);
        long newRowId = db.database.update(table, values, Contract.Bluda._ID + "= " + id, null);
        if (newRowId == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        bludaAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        bludaAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        Cursor cursor;
        DBHelper dbHeler;
        final int loaderID;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper dbHeler, int id) {
            super(context);
            this.dbHeler = dbHeler;
            loaderID = id;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor onLoadInBackground() {
            switch (loaderID) {
                case LOADER_BLUDA:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getBluda();
                    break;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит "ничего не происходит"? сам метод `onFavoriteButtonClick()` 
 не срабатывает? запись в БД не обновляется? в списке нет изменений после нажатия?

Comment: Сам метод отрабатывает, но по идее при нажатии на кнопку должно происходить добавление в избранное (т.е. поле like должно меняться) и записи на самой кнопке изменяться, но этого не происходит

Comment: то есть при повторном запуске пункт, который вы добавили в избранное не в избранном?

Comment: Вроде бы да.. В адаптере вы указывали для метода  нажатия на избранное like==1 объясните пожалуйста. В активити всегда будет передаваться значение 1? Или это проверка и если поле like равно 1 то будет передано true иначе  false?

Comment: Уже в избранном. Я немного изменила код в методе клика на кнопку избранного. Обновила вопрос. Можете глянуть и подсказать можно ли оставить так или получше как-то можно сделать?

Comment: а в чем изменение? вместо многоэтажной конструкции с if- else напишите: `int fav = isFavorite?0:1;` в результате в переменной fav будет 0, если isFavorite - true и 1, если там false, то есть инвертирует значение для записи в БД

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: значит проблема не в том, что в БД не записываются изменения, а втом, что после изменений адаптер не обновляется?

Comment: Обновляется уже.. Я нажимаю "Добавить в избранное" надпись меняется на кнопке, при повторном клике опять меняется надпись. Все работает пока что